# Method to create API for use by non-developers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a way so that other websites can embed data from out site onto theirs. For example, say someone wanted to show a slider of listings from ebay on their site, something like that.

However, I would want to just give the user some code to put on their site and it will pull the data in and display it - I don't want them to have to mess around with having to download any SDK's or have to write code to connect to the API or anything; something any webmaster should be able to handle.

I assume you could do something with `Javscript` where it would send a request to a file on our server which then returns the results? .... or even the remote site could load the data from a remote URL which is then loaded in an `iframe`?

I guess passing an `api key` would be helpful, though not a huge deal, but I guess that would pose a problem if it was just JS based as it could then be seen in the code?

Comment: If it's just to show information, such as ebay listings, do you really care about people seeing the identification info?  I wouldn't mind someone copying my key if it meant them advertising my stuff :D

Comment: Also, an iframe is probably the easiest way of doing what you need.  You could simply append the key to the src attribute and your end user would just have to copy and paste a line or 2 of code into their page to make it work.

Comment: @Archer Well no, I just thought of a key if some malicious site thought they would try and overload our server by sending mass amounts of traffic to the script or by loading it thousands of times on a page for example.

Comment: That would be simple enough to handle.  Don't try to make issues where there are none.  Simply only allow 1 response per minute, per referrer (for example).

Comment: That's a common issue, but attacking your homepage has exactly the same effect ;-)

Comment: ^^ That.  If you get too bogged down with security issues then you'll lose sleep over DDoS attacks and Java updates :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic and easy way to do such a thing involves [`<iframe>` tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

It's actually quite easy:

1. You create the view on your server as a standard page (like `example.com/embed/product_list?id=XXXX`)
2. You provide the appropriate code to your user `<iframe src="http://example.com/embed/product_list?id=XXXX" width="200" height="600"><p class="error">Your browser doesn't support iframes</p></iframe>`
3. They copy'n'paste it to their website and they're good to go

Pros:

- Easy setup for the client
- Easy setup for the provider (that's you)

Cons:

- Uses `<iframe>` (I don't like it, but it's somewhat acceptable)
- Client can't easily style it (CSS and stuff) (although you can use GET parameters to work around that)
- Same goes for layout (GET parameters hack works, but it's somewhat more complicated)
- Difficult access control. You can't easily define a list of allowed client websites